# ¿Como filtrar un JSON en typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, searchview

Tengo un proyecto Angular, mi controlador es un buscador, ya captura lo que escribo pero ahora lo que quiero es filtrar, segun lo que tengo entendido ya no tendria que poner el console.log, si no que tendria que colocar en su lugar la logica del filtrado, como podria hacerlo?

[image: Ahi esta en la parte de abajo con el CONSOLE.LOG]

[image: Con ese consle.log se puede ver en el navegador que captura lo que escribo]

Ahora lo que quiero es saber como filtrar el JSON que recibo arriba para poder hacer un filtrado, que deberia poner en lugar del console.log?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi JSON.

```js
[
  {
    "category": "FORMULARIOS",
    "items": [
      {
        "label": "Botones",
        "url": "ui-botones"
      },
      {
        "label": "Inputs",
        "url": "ui-inputs"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "CORREOS",
    "items": [
      {
        "label": "Facturas",
        "url": "ui-facturas"
      },
      {
        "label": "Movimientos",
        "url": "ui-movimientos"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "ALERTAS",
    "items": [
      {
        "label": "Toast",
        "url": "ui-toast"
      },
      {
        "label": "Toolips",
        "url": "ui-toolips"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hola. Por que valores quires buscar?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Por favor, evita subir imágenes de tu código, debes copiar y pegar el mismo en formato texto, de lo contrario es muy difícil reproducir el problema. Nadie querrá reescribir todo tu código desde la imagen ;) Por otro lado, dices: *tendría que poner la lógica del filtrado, como podría hacerlo?*. Esa pregunta es muy amplia, ¿ya tienes tu *lógica de filtrado*? si es así, te sugiero que la subas y expliques exactamente dónde tienes dificultad. Saludos

Comment: Hola Miguel. Te sugiero comenzar por esta [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

Comment: Por categoria el resultado sea los label

Answer (score 3):

Puedes filtrar tus datos de esta manera:

```js
this.searchForm.get('critery').valueChanges.subscribe(termino => {
  //Si el termino esta vacio, entonces volvemos a cargar 
  // todos los datos. 
  if (!termino.trim()) this.datosFiltrados = this.datos
  //Obtenemos los datos filtrados sin alterar los originales. 
  this.datosFiltrados = this.datos.filter(x => x.category.includes(termino.toUpperCase()))

})
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bv2vd8)

---

## Edicion

Para lograr que filtre por el sub array `items` en la propiedad `label` tienes que hacer estas modificaciones:

```
 this.searchForm.get("critery").valueChanges.subscribe(termino => {
      if (!termino.trim()) {
        this.datosFiltrados = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.datos));
        return;
      }

      this.datosFiltrados = this.datosFiltrados.filter(x => {
        let ctg = x.category.toLowerCase().includes(termino.toLowerCase());

        if (ctg) return true;

        x.items = x.items.filter(i =>
          i.label.toLowerCase().includes(termino.toLowerCase())
        );

        return x.items.length > 0;
      });
```

Tambien cuando se borra el termino de búsqueda se cargan todos los datos.

Te dejo [otro ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fmka8y)

Comment: Hola. Es mejor aquí. Aquí la comunidad puede abundar en las respuestas y enriquecer el conocimiento

Comment: Seria el mismo principio, solo anidado. Por cual campo de items quieres buscar?

Comment: @MiguelGallo edite la respuesta. Revisala por favor.

Comment: Me funciona bien, no se donde lo estes probando.